# Does concatenation create garbage?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I did search this info on the web, some say **yes** because javascript must create a new string object to store the result of the concatenation, some say **no** because string objects are not collected.

Maybe it depends on the context. For example, if I had an array of objects like

`animals["blue_dog","red_dog","yellow_cat","red_bird","green_bird"...]`

and I had a function with `animal` and `color` arguments, in this function I would access my object like this:

`animals[animal+"_"+color]`.

Most of the time I do concatenations when drawing text, which obviously doesn't happen a lot of times per frame. So even if it becomes garbage, it is insignificant. But when using a concatenation as an object's key, because of loops this concatenation could happen a thousand times per frame, and then this may become a problem.

Comment: Please provide some working code example.

Comment: Arrays are indexed with integers. `animals[animal+"_"+color]` is format for referencing object properties.

Comment: Even if this is a problem (it isn't), what's your alternative?

Comment: `var array = {
 "blue-dog": 1,
 "red-dog": 3,
 "red-fox": 2,
 "blue-fox": 4
}

var heads, tails, i;
heads = ["blue", "red"];
tails = ["dog", "fox"];

var CONST = 1000000;
for( i = 0 ; i < CONST; i++ ) {
 array[heads[i%2] + '-' + tails[i%2]];
}`

Comment: Try this code with active Profiler in Chrome to check your theory.

Answer (score 2):

Doing something like `animals[color + "_" + animal]` creates a temporary value for accessing the object. That temporary will be collected either by the garbage collector or at the end of the block/function call (implementation dependent).

My assumption (based on my own experience in working with compilers) is that since the result isn't stored in a variable, it will be placed on the stack and released once the function completes. But, again, this depends on how the engine is written.

*I'm in no way an expert on compilers.*

Answer (score 1):

May or may not, depends on how optimal is the compiler.

This `a + b + c` is `(a + b) + c` so you have two concatenations. Result of (a + b) will be a temporary object (string here). That temporary is a garbage.

For the given expression this form `a.concat(b,c)` is conceptually better. It in principle does not require intermediate temporaries.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, concatenating strings can definitely produce garbage. I had a scenario where I had a lot of cells in a large table and each cell could have a different css class (from a set of combinations of maybe 30 different combinations) assigned. Doing this the normal way:

`const class = group + empty + active;`

Would produce a lot of garbage. I created a memoized function that received a bitmask as argument which would produce the class string and got rid of the garbage that way.

This reply is an excellent list of what to avoid:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18411275